# The correct way to identify a regular expression of the sort [variableName].add(

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm looking for a clean way to identify occurrences of [variableName] followed by the exact string `.add(`.

A variable name is a string which contains one or more characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and an underscore.

One more thing is that it cannot start with any of the characters from 0-9, but I don't mind ignoring this condition because there are no such cases in the text that I need to parse anyway.

I've been following several tutorials, but the farthest I got was finding all occurrences of what I've referred to above as "variableName":

```
import re

txt = "The _rain() in+ Spain5"
x = re.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", txt)
print(x)
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w+(?=\.add\()', txt)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You're a champ!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\w+(?=\.add\()', txt, flags=re.ASCII)
```

The regex matches:

- `\w+`  - 1+ word chars (due to `re.ASCII`, it only matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]` chars)
- `(?=\.add\()` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `.add(` substring.